# Saving values from a Checkboxlist into a MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql

What's the best way to store values from a Checkboxlist in MySQL?

Should I use columns for each checkbox item or is there a more efficient way to save this data?

[This is what the designs look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ewL.png) - see the list of services at the bottom of the form.

Comment: please provide with code you tried so far and problem you facing.

Comment: I don't know what is your exact checkboxlist items , but you can store something like value1###value2###value3###valuen